# Pre-visualising multiple pictures when selected

Tags: javascript

I have this code to pre-visualise the pic we selected in the form.

It works fine when there is only one picture but I don't know what do modify if I want multiple files to be selected and previsualised for multiple pictures.
I tried to copy paste this one time per pic but seems not to work like this (I am not so good in js).

How should I modify it to make it work for image 1, image 2, image3, etc...

```
function readURL(input) {
              if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                 var reader = new FileReader();
                 reader.onload = function (e) {
                   $('#image1').css('backgroundImage', "url(" + e.target.result + ")" );
                 }
                 reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
              }
            }
            $("#profile-img1").change(function(){
               readURL(this);
            });
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create image gallery?

Comment: I have a image gallery, I just want to be let the user see the pic he selected with input file.
And as I have multiple pics I need to duplicate this process... but just duplicating the code and changing the ID's don't work